# How to get standard form of parabola from oblique parabola??

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

The given parabloa is $x^2+2xy+y^2+4x-4y-4=0$. How do I convert it to $x^2=4ax$ or $y^2=4ay$ (aka standard form)?

Comment: Are you looking for a change of coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

The standard parabola can be written as $L_1^2 =4A L_2$, where $L_1,L_2$ are perpendicular and normalized lines.The length of lataus rectum is $4A$  So here we have
$$x^2-+xy+y^2+4x-4y-4=0 \implies (x+y)^2=4(y-x+1). $$
$$\implies\left(\frac{(x+y)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=2\sqrt{2}\frac{(y-x+1)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
The length of the latus rectum is $2\sqrt{2}$ the equation of the axis of the parabola is $x+y=0$ and Tangent at vertex is $y-x+1=0$.

Comment: Did $\sqrt{2}$ come as the co-efficient of $x$ and $y$

Comment: It is all clear please concentrate on the solution.

Comment: No I mean you randomly took $sqrt{2}$ in the denominator. My best guess it's the co-efficient of $x$ and $y$ and $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The normalized form of $ax+by+c=0$ is $\frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ you are right $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{1+1}$ and it is not random.

Comment: Thank you brother, may Allah bless you

Comment: You may now select the answer.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry but I'm new here